# Multiple Try Except when the value may not be present

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

I need to check one or another environment variable.

With casual variables - I can use:

```
if var1:
    print('Var1 found')
elif var2:
    print('Var2 found')
else:
    print('Neither Var1 nor Var2 not found')
```

How can I do same for environment variables?

I can't use `if/else`, because of if variable not found - `os.environ` will raize `KeyError`:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'BAMBOO_WORKING_DIRECTORY'
```

If I'll do two `try/except`, like:

```
try:
    r = os.environ['Var1']
except KeyError as error:
    print('Var1 not found')

try:
    r = os.environ['Var2']
except KeyError as error:
    print('Var2 not found')
```

So, it will check both of them. But I need `Var1` or `Var2`.

Add `if/else` after first try/except, to check `if r:` an call second `try/except` if not? Will looks disgusting...

Comment: Use ``os.environ.get(key, default)``. e.g: ``if os.environ.get("FOO", None):``

Comment: @JamesMills could you add this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *exact* equivalent of your `if/elif` for known variables (*but for environment variables*) would be:

```
from os import environ

if environ.get("VAR1"):
    print('VAR1 found')
elif environ.get("VAR2"):
    print('VAR2 found')
else:
    print('Neither VAR1 nor VAR2 not found')
```

Since `os.environ` is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) has a signature of `dict.get(key, [default])` where `default` defaults to `None` you can take advantage of this and get `None` back for key(s) that don't exist (*which evaluate `False`ly*).

Answer (score 4):

`os.environ` is a dict, so you can use the `.get` call on it with default value.

If you use the two .get calls in conjunction, then this will get you the first variable, if it is present (because of python short circuiting), else it will get you the second one.

So essentially, the code is simplified to:

```
r = os.environ.get('Var1', "") or os.environ.get('Var2', "")
```

In this case, there is no need of a try - except block.

Chain this slightly longer, and you can get the expression which will give the default value as well:

```
>>> r = os.environ.get('Var1', "") or os.environ.get('Var2', "") or (
    "Neither Var1 nor Var2 not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `for` loop?

```
for varname in ['Var1', 'Var2']:
    try:
        r = os.environ['Var1']
        break
    except KeyError as error:
        print('{} not found'.format(varname))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your `try` statements

```
try:
    r = os.environ['Var1']

    try:
        r = os.environ['Var2']
    except KeyError as error:
        print('Var2 not found')

except KeyError as error:
    print('Var1 not found')
```